# Reason of ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379 Error When Connecting Nest.js with Docker and Redis

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, redis, nestjs

I am working on a Nest.js project where I use Redis as the caching manager. I noticed that I need to use different code on my local iMac and the deployed EC2 instance when connecting to Redis.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
```

I set the network names to be the same in docker-compose.yml, but it still failed.
I also set the container name and host name to be the same, but it still failed.

I succeeded in connecting using a different approach.
I had to use different code depending on the operating system.

On my **M1 iMac**, Nest.js only works with Redis as a caching manager when I use the socket property when registering it:

```
// M1 iMac
CacheModule.register({
  store: redisStore,
  socket: { host: "redis", port: 6379 },
}),
```

On my **Ubuntu 22.04 EC2** instance, Nest.js with Redis as a caching manager only works when I use the host and port properties:

```
// Ubuntu 22.04
CacheModule.register({
  store: redisStore,
  host: "redis",
  port: 6379,
}),
```

I struggled with this for a few days until I stumbled upon this solution and resolved it by setting environment variables to make it work in each environment. However, I couldn't find any information about this online or in the official documentation. Can someone explain why this situation occurs?

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - redis:/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 10
    networks:
      - samplenetwork
  web:
    image: shinyubin/fow-be:latest
    container_name: fow-be
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    environment:
       - ENVIRONMENT=production
    networks:
      - samplenetwork
    depends_on:
      - redis
volumes:
  redis:
    driver: local
networks:
  samplenetwork:
```

In addition, the following code represents the approach I used to resolve it.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    CacheModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        const environment = configService.get<string>("ENVIRONMENT");
        const redisConfig =
          environment === "production"
            ? {
                store: redisStore,
                host: "redis",
                port: 6379,
              }
            : {
                store: redisStore,
                socket: { host: "redis", port: 6379 },
              };
        return {
          ...redisConfig,
        };
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```